# What are some of the best materials to use for building a fiber laser safety enclosure of 1060nm - 1085nm?

Tags: material-science, laser, spectroscopy, fiber-optics, infrared-radiation

I have gotten a 30W JPT-LP Litemarker Fiber Laser which has a wavelength range of 1060nm - 1085nm. Before even thinking about using it, i want to build an enclosure for it to increase the level of safety i have in my workspace for myself as well as others who may accidentally be exposed (i also have 1064nm laser goggles). I have ordered a window of OD8+ for 1030nm - 2200nm which is applicable to my fiber laser wavelength and i want to fit this onto the body of my fiber laser safety enclosure to be able to view into it. However, i cannot for the life of me, find what is a highly effective material to use for the fiber laser safety enclosure body. SOS!

I have desperately tried to find answers everywhere including reading a few studies without much scientific background knowledge to internalize these extensive research papers. I've heard of everything from paper, plastic, wood, metal, "you need specific materials because Infrared light can penetrate opaque materials", "Opaque/black won't block Infrared light", to "any electricity conductive material" and "black absorbs Infrared light".

I understand that Near-Infrared, Mid-Infrared and Far-Infrared radiation/light would interact with materials differently to each other, hence why i see so many contradicting information as the three Infrared types are probably lumped into "Infrared radiation" and therefore would in one way or another and partially, be true to the information i've found, but it does not help for my specific wavelength of 1060nm - 1085nm which i understand as being Near-Infrared.

So posting here is my last hope.

For more information about my fiber laser, here is exactly what it is:
https://www.cloudraylaser.com/products/copy-of-china-warehouse-cloudray-20w-30w-50w-litemarker-fiber-marking-machine?_pos=3&_sid=03405abcf&_ss=r

Thank you for giving your time to reading my post and i hope to hear your response/s!

Comment: What's wrong with aluminum? Or stainless steel if you like the look better? And why a window? Why not just install a small USB camera on the inside? That's absolutely safe and it might compare in cost to the window material these days.

Comment: Consult your local Laser Safety Officer to comply with your. Local requirements.

Comment: My acquired understanding is that for fiber laser enclosures, it is better to use a material that absorbs rather than reflect. This is because materials that absorb effectively, "convert" Near-Infrared radiation/light into "heat". Therefore, effectively eliminating the   hazard and transforming it into heat which can be controlled with air circulation and heat radiation away from the enclosure. 

However, materials that are known to reflect Near-Infrared light/radiation, keeps the buildup of heat/reflections in & increases the chances of it to damage the exposed laser part (though unlikely).